# Trying to mutliply the result of a column and a number but keep getting error in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i am trying to create a dynamic action that calculates the commission of an estate agent by multiplying the asking price by the commission rate 6%. but i keep getting an error in oracle. i am a beginner to oracle. any help will bee appreciated.

```
:P13_ASKING_PRICE * 0.06
```

this is the code i put which multiplies the asking price by 0.06

but i get this error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 145: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "*"
>   when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; indicator

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a dynamic action was it? Apex expects

```
:P13_RESULT := :P13_ASKING_PRICE * 0.06;
```

not just

```
:P13_ASKING_PRICE * 0.06
```

**[EDIT]**

I've tested it right now; I created two items on a page, P13_ASKING_PRICE which expects a value to be entered, and P13_RESULT which will display the result.

- "Set value" dynamic action on P13_ASKING_PRICE item
- Set type: "PL/SQL Function body"
- PL/SQL Function body: `return (:P13_ASKING_PRICE * 0.06);`
- Items to submit: P13_ASKING_PRICE
- Affected elements:

  - selection type: item(s)
  - item(s): P13_RESULT
- Fire on initialization: No

That's all; works well, so - try it.

Comment: Aha; you made it work in the meantime, while I was editing my message. Have a look, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the problem im facing now is that when i input the asking price the commission doesnt change. i noticed that when i reload the page thats when the commission value shows. im using a change event when value is not null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; did you apply what I suggested in the edited part of my message?